# Configuring NGINX to host a React app and a WordPress blog in a sub route

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, nginx

We have a React app hosted on `www.xyz.com` and want to add a WordPress blog under `www.xyz.com/blog` route.

Tried to configure nginx to support it. Here's the current nginx config file:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        server_name www.xyz.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        location ^~ /blog {
                index index.php;

                location ~ \.php$ {
                        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
                }

                location ~ /\.ht {
                        deny all;
                }
        }
}
```

It kinda works but when I visit, `www.xyz.com/blog/wp-admin`, it keeps redirecting to the same page.

So, my question is: why is this happening?

Another question: I also saw that I can potentially use `proxy_pass` directive. Is it possible? If so, how exactly can I do it?